# Cannot get object to change position using tween

Tags: three.js, tween.js

Apologies for asking this, but I am losing my mind.

In the context of a three.js scene I have built a cube with the following bit of code.

```
var gcap = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2 ); 
mcap = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x3182bd, wireframe: false, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5} ); 

cap = new THREE.Mesh( gcap, mcap ); 
cap.position.set( - 12, 19, 0 );
gcap.center();
cap.rotation.z = (28 * Math.PI)/180; //convert to radians
app.scene.add(cap);
```

So why does this tween not work (and by not working I mean there is not noticeable change in the scene):

```
new TWEEN.Tween(cap.position)
      .to(-12, 19, 100 ).start();
```

but this one does:

```
        new TWEEN.Tween(app.controls.target).to({
             x: 31/2,
             y: 29/2,
             z: 11/2
         }).start();
```

I realize this is probably a super-dumb question, but I'm new to tween (and really three.js in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.to()` you have to pass an object of the same structure that you pass in `.Tween()`, fully or partially. It depends on what values of the object you want to change.

And the second paremeter in `.to()` is duration.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var box1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
box1.position.set(-3, 0, 0);
scene.add(box1);
var box2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "blue",
  wireframe: true
}));
box2.position.set(3, 0, 0);
scene.add(box2);

var tween1 = new TWEEN.Tween(box1.position) // here you pass the position {x, y, z}
  .to({ // here you pass an object with properties you want to change (now you want to change all of them)
    x: 1,
    y: 3,
    z: -2
  }, 2000).delay(500).repeat(Infinity).yoyo(true).start();

var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(box2.position) // the same, position {x, y, z}
  .to({ // but you want to change only y-coordinate, so you pass an object of {y}
    y: 3
  }, 1000).delay(500).repeat(Infinity).yoyo(true).start();



render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use your code to help diagnose the problem... namely that the code I am generating included this flag:     app.scene.autoUpdate = false;